# Is it possible to use the interface on a remote machine which I can SSH into?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, network-interface

I can SSH into a machine which has a wifi adapter connected, with interface wlan0. Can I use its interface (wlan0) on my client machine ?

As an example, if I want to run iwconfig (or any tool which can use wlan0) on the interface without it being installed on the server, but is installed on the client machine.

Both the server and client are running linux.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to run `iwconfig` on your server without it being installed by virtue of it being installed on the client? If so, no, that will never work.

Comment: @Logan Yes, whether I can forward the interface.

Comment: Is the adapter a USB adapter?

Comment: I'm curious - what's the end goal of this? Running iwconfig on the client would make more sense. There's legitimate uses for this, and this is potentially a glorious hack but I'm curious to what the use of this could be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the wifi card is actually a USB adapter, then yes, you can do it.

The solution to this is the use of a technique called USB over IP. There is one Open Source solution, plus 2 commercial ones.

The OS solution is [usbip](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-modify-your-gnu-linux-box-to-serve-as-a-usb-over-ip-server). You will have to download the server-side package on the remote machine, and the client side-package on your own machine. It is **very** easy to use, and the page above has all the details you wish.

After the final command,

```
  sudo usbip -a <server-ip> device_to_be_attached
```

the USB device will apear as if it were on your pc. Careful when you try to bring it up as a network interface, because, if you let network manager configure your routing table, it will completely mess it up. It is wiser to turn network-manager off before staring the usbip connection, and do it all by hand. But it can be done.

The commercial solutions I know are

Fabula-Tech USB-over-Network:

http://www.fabulatech.com/usb-over-network.html

Eltima Software USB Network Gate:

http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet

There may be others, cannot say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not proxy your local requests through that box?

```
$ ssh -ND 8080 your.machine
```

This will act as a SOCKS server on your local machine and any requests will be forwarded to `your.machine`.  Of course, this assumes that on the remote machine the wifi is set up and the default route is through that wlan0 device.  You can do that with iwconfig on the *remote* machine.

What you imply to ask, whether you can forward the actual wlan0 device to your machine, that's not possible currently.

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention that routing traffic through that SOCKS proxy to the other machine requires client support, e.g. in firefox you'd have to adjust your network settings.  It's *not* a transparent tunnel.

In case you wanted a local device that will route traffic through the other machine (where in turn it would route the traffic through wlan0) you could use a simple tunnel or a VPN.

```
$ ip tunnel add tuntowlan0 mode gre remote <remote-address>
```

but this will require some fiddling with the routing table on the local machine if you didn't want *all* traffic to go through there, and make sure ip forwarding is enabled on the remote box.

Comment: *"whether you can forward the actual wlan0 device to your machine, that's not possible currently."* Yes, I wanted to know whether I can forward the interface.

Comment: Not natively, you can use a local device tuntowlan0 that has an endpoint on your local machine *and* another endpoint on the remote machine, and then you'd have to set up routing such that all traffic to tuntowlan0 ends up at wlan0, I think that's the best you can do